# Change behaviour of Cart/Controller Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I have a technical issue I hope to solve with your help:

When you add  a product into cart it is done by the CartController and its Cart Class. Within the Cart class `Cart.php` there is a method called `updateQty`. Within this function there is a check if cart already contains product or not. If cart contains product then increase its quantity when operator == up and decrease its quantity when operator == down, else if cart does not contain product then add product to cart when operator == up.

This is the certain function mentioned from Cart.php

```
/* Check if the product is already in the cart */
$result = $this->containsProduct($id_product, $id_product_attribute, (int) $id_customization, (int) $id_address_delivery);


/* Update quantity if product already exist */
if ($result) {
    if ($operator == 'up') {
        $sql = 'SELECT stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity
                        FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product p
                        ' . Product::sqlStock('p', $id_product_attribute, true, $shop) . '
                        WHERE p.id_product = ' . $id_product;

        $result2 = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
        $product_qty = (int) $result2['quantity'];
        // Quantity for product pack
        if (Pack::isPack($id_product))
            $product_qty = Pack::getQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute);
        $new_qty = (int) $result['quantity'] + (int) $quantity;
        $qty = '+ ' . (int) $quantity;

        if (!Product::isAvailableWhenOutOfStock((int) $result2['out_of_stock']))
            if ($new_qty > $product_qty)
                return false;
    }
    else if ($operator == 'down') {
        $qty = '- ' . (int) $quantity;
        $new_qty = (int) $result['quantity'] - (int) $quantity;
        if ($new_qty < $minimal_quantity && $minimal_quantity > 1)
            return -1;
    } else
        return false;

    /* Delete product from cart */
    if ($new_qty <= 0)
        return $this->deleteProduct((int) $id_product, (int) $id_product_attribute, (int) $id_customization);
    else if ($new_qty < $minimal_quantity)
        return -1;
    else
        Db::getInstance()->execute('
                    UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart_product`
                    SET `quantity` = `quantity` ' . $qty . ', `date_add` = NOW()
                    WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int) $id_product .
                (!empty($id_product_attribute) ? ' AND `id_product_attribute` = ' . (int) $id_product_attribute : '') . '
                    AND `id_cart` = ' . (int) $this->id . (Configuration::get('PS_ALLOW_MULTISHIPPING') && $this->isMultiAddressDelivery() ? ' AND `id_address_delivery` = ' . (int) $id_address_delivery : '') . '
                    LIMIT 1'
        );
}
/* Add product to the cart */
elseif ($operator == 'up') {
    $sql = 'SELECT stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity
                    FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product p
                    ' . Product::sqlStock('p', $id_product_attribute, true, $shop) . '
                    WHERE p.id_product = ' . $id_product;

    $result2 = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);

    // Quantity for product pack
    if (Pack::isPack($id_product))
        $result2['quantity'] = Pack::getQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute);

    if (!Product::isAvailableWhenOutOfStock((int) $result2['out_of_stock']))
        if ((int) $quantity > $result2['quantity'])
            return false;

    if ((int) $quantity < $minimal_quantity)
        return -1;

    $result_add = Db::getInstance()->insert('cart_product', array(
        'id_product' => (int) $id_product,
        'id_product_attribute' => (int) $id_product_attribute,
        'id_cart' => (int) $this->id,
        'id_address_delivery' => (int) $id_address_delivery,
        'id_shop' => $shop->id,
        'quantity' => (int) $quantity,
        'date_add' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'customprice' => (float) $customprice,
    ));

    if (!$result_add)
        return false;
}
```

This is cart's logical behaviour because if you already have a product in the cart and lets say you press again add-to-cart button for same product, it has same result as if you would press the plus-button in cart for increasing product quantity. It would be bad behaviour if pretashop would add same product to cart twice.

Everything is fine so far if you use Prestashop the regular way when every of your products has a fix price set in backoffice.

But in may case customer can add product to cart with a custom price. I fetch this variable $customprice with `Tools::getValue('variable')` in `cart.php` and saves it in the database as you can see in the last sql query. So now when you add product into cart with a custom price product is added into cart and customprice is saved. But when you go back to product page and add same product but with a different custom price then of course cart acting like this:

It only increases the quantity of the first product you already added to cart because this product already exists in cart. The second custom price is beeing ignored.

Somebody has any idea in which file I have to change things to tell the cart controller that when same product is added to cart BUT with different price it should not increase the quantity of the first item instead controller should add the product again into cart with the new price like it would be a different product!!???

Any help is appreciated

Best regards

Comment: Hey @Pedram Did you manage to find any solution to this? I have to do something similar. In my case the products are exactly the same, except I want so that each of them appears as a different product in the cart.